# URL path based routing on Azure

Tags: azure

I'd need the following config on Azure:

- requests to www.domain.com goes to an App Service (call it MainAppService)
- requests to www.domain.com/blog/* to a different App Service (call it BlogAppService)

It is important that the url stays www.domain.com/blog/something (a simple redirect to blog.domain.com/something won't work for me here).

MainAppService is a .Net Core app while BlogAppService should be php (yes, WordPress). I wonder if Azure Application Gateway is the only option. Any code based solution without the need to install AAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want a code-based solution, you may consider adding [URL rewrite rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-configuration-and-management#how-do-i-add-or-edit-a-url-rewrite-rule) in web app service. It seems that [Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) only works in one web app service. That is, you could not redirect HTTP-host `www.domain.com` to `blog.domain.com` based on rewrite rule.

As your configuration, I think Azure application gateway is an easy and better way to make it.

Configuration example:

[Create an application gateway with path-based routing rules using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal)

[How to map URL path-based rules in application gateway for your Azure web app service](http://devchat.live/en/2018/07/02/how-to-map-url-path-based-rules-in-application-gateway-for-your-azure-web-app-service/)